# Stacky Yoneda lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, yoneda-lemma

I’m studying differentiable stacks from [this paper](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Eginot/papers/DiffStacksIGG2013.pdf) (Gregory Ginot), and I’m trying to understand why the “Yoneda embedding” from the category of differentiable manifolds $\textbf{Man}$ to the category of “categories fibered in groupoids” (which for simplicity I’ll call “prestacks”) $\mathbf{Prestacks}$ is a fully faithful functor.

(If you don’t know about prestacks you can simply substitute $\mathbf{Prestacks} $ with the category of functors $\text{Fun}(-,\textbf{Man})$, where an arrow between $F:\mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{Man}$ and $G:\mathbf{D}\to \mathbf{Man}$ is a functor $H:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{D}$ such that $G\circ H=F$. This is possible because the former category is a full subcategory of the latter.)

The Yoneda embedding maps a manifold to the prestack $\pi_M:\text{Hom}(-,M)\to \textbf{Man}$. This prestack maps an object $f$ to $\text{dom}(f)$ and an it basically doesn’t modify the arrows.

Regarding the arrows, the Yoneda embedding maps an arrow $F$ to the standard pullback of smooth maps $F^\ast$.

To prove that the Yoneda embedding is a bijection I need to prove that for any manifolds $M,N$ the map induced by the Yoneda embedding

$$C^\infty(M,N)\to \text{Hom}_{\textbf{Prestacks}}(\pi_M,\pi_N),\ \ \ F\mapsto F^*$$

is bijective. The only possible candidate for the inverse map is $\alpha \mapsto \alpha(\text{id}_M)$. Obviously $F^\ast (\text{id}_M)=F$, so this direction is easy.

I’m having some trouble in the other direction. I can’t prove that $(\alpha (\text{id}_M))^*=\alpha$. Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "prestacks" already has a well established meaning (the functors to descent data need to be fully faithful) so you probably shouldn't use the word prestack to refer to Grothendieck fibrations above $Man$.

The trick is to see that not any functor $yM\to YN$ is allowed as a map of Grothendieck fibrations, but only those which preserve cartesian arrows. An object in the $L$th fiber of $yM$ is a map $u:L\to M$ of smooth manifolds. There is additionally a horizontal cartesian arrow $u\leadsto id_M$ in the total category of $yM$ which indicates that $u$ as an object in $yM$ is the reindexing of $id_M$ along the morphism $u:L\to M$ in the base. Any map $\alpha:yM\to yN$ must send that cartesian arrow $u\leadsto id_M$ to a cartesian arrow $\alpha_L(u)\leadsto \alpha_M(id_M)$ also lying above $u:L\to M$ in the base. You can check that this implies that $\alpha_L(u) = \alpha_M(id_M)\circ u$. This means that the action of $\alpha$ is completely determined once you know what $\alpha_M(id_M)$ is.

The argument above is a special case of the argument which you do when you prove the fibered Yoneda lemma. The fibered Yoneda lemma says that
\begin{align}
Fib_{Man}(yM,C) \to C_M, A\mapsto A(id_M)
\end{align}
is an equivalence for every Grothendieck fibration $C$ above $Man$. The fact that $C$ is a Grothendieck fibration is very important, since that means that the action of some 1-cell $A:yM\to C$ or 2-cell out of $yM$ is completely determined by its action on the generic object $id_M$ of the discrete fibration $yM$.

Edit: To see that $\alpha(f) = \alpha(id_M)\circ f$ first note that there must be a cartesian arrow $\alpha(f) \leadsto \alpha(id_M)$ lying in above $f$ in the total category of $yN$. This cartesian arrow is the image of the cartesian arrow $f\leadsto id_M$ under $\alpha$. There is a canonical cartesian arrow $\alpha(id_M)\circ f \leadsto \alpha(id_M)$ above $f$ in the total category of $yN$. By the universal property of cartesian arrows we have that $\alpha(id_M)\circ f$ must be isomorphic to $\alpha(f)$ via a vertical isomorphism in the total category of $yN$. But the only vertical isomorphisms in the total category of $yN$ are identities, since $yN$ is a discrete fibered category. Hence we see that $\alpha(f) = \alpha(id_M)\circ f$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but could you explain more explicitely what are the cartesian arrows? The paper I'm reading doesn't talk about them at all...

Comment: @Kandinskij In the text that your reading, definition 1.1 i) "For every object $\overline U$  such that $\pi(\overline U) = U$ and arrow $V\to U$ there is an arrow $\overline V\to \overline U$ such that..." That arrow $\overline V\to \overline U$ is called a cartesian arrow.

Comment: @Kandinskij A good reference for fibered categories is Streicher's "Fibered Categories a la Jean Benabou". You will find cartesian arrows and the fibered Yoneda lemma in it.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what you mean with “cartesian arrow”. But I still don’t see how this implies that $\alpha(f)=\alpha(\text{id}_M)\circ f$

Comment: @Kandinskij This follows from the fact that $yN$ is a discrete fibration. There is only one way to reindexing an object along a morphism in the base, or in other words the cartesian lifts are truely unique. I added the argument at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Kandinskij You're welcome :)